# Hours and Minutes calculation in Dataview webpart

Tags: xslt, data-view-web-part, calculated-column, xml, dataview

I have a DataView Webpart, to display XML data using XML File connection.

I use the below formula to calculate the day difference between 2 dates:

```
"(number(ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(Date2)))) - number(ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(Date1))))) div 864000000000"
```

Now I would like to calculate the Hours and minutes difference between the 2 dates. I'm scratching my head to achieve this. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you div by `864000000000` you will get Days.

In order to get Hours you can use the same formula with div by `36000000000` and for minutes div by `600000000`

`ddwrt:DateTimeTick` function returns the number of “ticks” since Jan 1 1900

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/109ae6f2-ea16-464f-978e-b565a69721a5/sharepoint-designer-2010-determine-if-todays-date-is-within-x-days-of-a-start-date-column-using?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Comment: This didnt work as i expected. It simply multiples the day X 24. What i am looking for is, I have a start date and time : 11/2/2014 14:00:00 and a end date time : 11/27/2014 16:00:00.I need to calculate the time difference between the two times and display the result as 2 hours.Is it possible?

Comment: With the above formula,it displays only the hours greater than 1 day and that too as a whole hours for a day namely 24(1*24),48(2*24),72(3*24),etc and not exactly the time difference between 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a post](http://sympmarc.com/2009/07/22/date-arithmetic-in-sharepoint-dvwps/) that has helped me in the past with very similar challenges.

It has a hyperlink to an XSL document that contains several templates for date arithmetic operations. Hope this helps.